# How fast can Quicksilver run?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In the movie *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, it looks like Quicksilver runs so fast that everything is almost at a standstill. Just how fast can he run? Speed of light?

There is a scene where he takes care of the security at the Pentagon. He threw a plate at the security officer and the plate flies a bit then stops (or he speeds up even more). At whatever speed he runs and throwing an object at that speed, I would imagine that plate will go right through the security officer. This also ties into how fast he is going IF he sped up after throwing the plate, then he must have increased his speed by a lot since the plate he threw should be traveling at a high velocity to begin with.

Also I read in the wiki that he is the son of Magneto... I guess that's not the case in the movie?

Comment: In the movie, it is not explicitly stated whether or not Pietro is the son of Erik, but there is a quick line from Pietro along the lines of, "Oh, you can control magnetism, my mother knew someone like that." There is also a shot at the end of Pietro and his younger sister. In the comics, he is the brother of both Scarlet Witch (Wanda Maximoff) and Polaris (Lorna Dane).

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I do remember he said that. I guess in the movie they both do not know about their relationship

Comment: It'll probably come up in future films (that Magneto is Quicksilver's father).

Comment: This is in no way canon, more of an observation on the film, but the films looked more like Quicksilver can either slow down time to everyone but him or increase the speed of his own timestream so everyone else appears to going slower to him. In his scene in DOFP, he stands still or walks several times - if he had been running at roughly the speed of sound, there would have been a higher stopping distance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In the comics**

[Marvel's site](http://marvel.com/universe/Quicksilver) states:

> Quicksilver possessed superhuman speed, and **could travel on foot at speeds exceeding the speed of sound for hundreds of miles before tiring;** he could "fly" for short distances by flapping his arms or "vibrating" his legs; he could also use his speed to create cyclones, dodge machine gun and laser fire, and run up walls and across water.

However, his powers are amplified later on.

> Following the loss of his mutant nature, Quicksilver exposed himself to the Terrigen Mists, resulting in him **now possessing the power to vibrate his atoms so quickly he travels forward in time.** His molecular speed that he generates displaces him out of the mainstream time/space so that he is able to propel himself into the future. He can leap from thirty seconds to up to twelve days, and remain for several minutes to several hours before being recalled to his present time once his body tires, or he can return at will before his time is up. As he returns from his trip, he returns the exact moment he left so as to appear that he has been gone for half a nano-second. He is able to bring inorganic objects from the future back to his correct time, although it has yet been shown what would happen if he attempted to bring organic objects with him.

---

**In the X-Men movies by Fox**

The movie's [official website](http://www.x-menmovies.com/#!/character/quicksilver) simply lists his maximum speed as "faster than the speed of sound".

[image: x-men movie site screencap]

---

**In the Marvel Cinematic Universe**

Unfortunately, no concrete information regarding Quicksilver's maximum speed has been made public as of yet. During the course of the movie, we see Quicksilver outrunning Mjolnir and arrows, as well as altering the trajectory of arrow in mid-flight. This is not necessarily indicative of the limits of his abilities. Even the junior novelization only describes his speed as "faster than a bullet train" and "faster than a jet".

Comment: Interesting, to dodge laser, doesn't that mean he has to run faster than the speed of light?

Comment: @Huangism Assuming you're talking about laser beams of light, yes (and not necessarily laser-type weapons which often aren't actually lasers). But I don't recall him dodging lasers in the movie.

Comment: @Huangism, Dodging a laser fired from a weapon doesn't necessarily require moving faster-than-light. It requires moving faster than your attacker's reflexes can aim and pull the trigger.

Comment: The films looked more like Quicksilver can either slow down time to everyone but him or increase the speed of his own timestream so everyone else appears to going slower to him. In his scene in DOFP, he stands still or walks several times - if he had been running at roughly the speed of sound, there would have been a higher stopping distance.

Comment: I don't think he slows down time, he just moves so fast so everyone around him seems to be standing still or moving very very slow

Comment: @Huangism I don't think it was the intention of the film makers, but it works better in my head. When he throws a plate at a guy, it gets just out of his reach and begins to slow down eventually moving as if he had thrown in at people speeds rather than throwing it a several hundred miles an hour. In my mind, the plate left his timestream and entered the normal timestream, slowing down for Quicksilvers perspective, but from the plates perspective it never changed speed. Like I said, just a small fan theory really. It would explain why the friction on his legs wouldn't rip him apart as well.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I was thinking since he threw the plate in the opposite direction, so his speed going forward offset the speed of the plate going the opposite direction hence the slow down. If he throw it at normal human speed and the plate traveled a bit, then everything around him should of been in real time but it didn't seem that way

Comment: @Huangism Even if that is the case, he can somehow go from running near the speed of sound to standing still in less than a metre, which just isn't possible if his power is indeed moving really quick. From a physics perspective, my time stream theoery makes sense until we see him running on the walls, which I can't explain just yet.

Comment: @DrRDizzle and then there is that scene where he runs with magneto and magneto was out of breathe after less than a second at traveling so fast. So many things that non-mutant science cannot explain lol

Comment: He's a mutant, and most mutants have physics defying powers. He can accelerate from 0 to god knows what speed in single digit feet, and stop in the same distance in all mediums, comic, cartoon, movies.

Comment: Virtually all powers have required secondary powers. Super-acceleration, for example, often goes with superspeed. After all, is moving at *well* over 700 mph (necessary in order to dodge a bullet, let alone run around a room while it travels straight) really so awesome if it take minutes to get up to that speed? To get that super-acceleration, they need super-friction. Super-friction at super-speed creates super-heat, so they need super-dissipation. It may look like the Flash or Quicksilver is running, but whatever they're doing only *looks* like running.

Answer (score -2):

Yes we all know that Quicksilver can run super fast. Some would say he runs faster than the speed of sound. But if you think further back into the comics he actually can run at the speed of time. Thus making everything come to a stand still. However in *Days of Future Past*, he is portrayed as having his powers at full level, when in the comics he only got around to his full flex of powers during his time with the Avengers 80 years later give or take.

But the thing that really gets me thinking his if he can run at the speed of sound or whatever. In the scene of the end credits of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* he is trying to get out of his captivity from Hydra. Hello, if you can run almost as fast as time you could just vibrate your body to a certain speed and walk straight out. And the Scarlet Witch for crying out loud. Her powers have devastating effects. She's known to be one of the most badass super heroines (don't let me forget when she goes bat shit crazy she also wipes out half of the friggin Marvel universe heroes included) but Quicksilver can definitely put time in a bottle.