# Why doesn't Quicksilver create sonic booms?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In both the comics and *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Quicksilver is described as being able to [break the sound barrier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58484/5184).

[Wikipedia explains sonic booms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom):

> A sonic boom is the sound associated with the shock waves created by an object traveling through the air faster than the speed of sound. Sonic booms generate enormous amounts of sound energy, sounding much like an explosion. The crack of a supersonic bullet passing overhead is an example of a sonic boom in miniature.

In all of the mediums that I've seen Quicksilver portrayed (comics, cartoons, movies), Quicksilver's motion causes wind, but never a sonic boom.

**If Quicksilver is really running faster than the speed of sound, why is there no sonic boom created?**

Comment: It goes to the same place that Cyclops' laser eye-beams and Mystique's extra mass come from.

Comment: Erm, magic? Or possibly midi-chlorians. I forget which. FOr the record, The Flash has been known to cause sonic booms; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuA0x8zKWvI

Comment: @SJuan76, So, Pietro should be making Sonic "Pops"? :)

Comment: @evilsoup -  Cyclops doesn't shoot lasers but force beams out of his eyes, though they do come from another dimension according to Chris Claremont =]

Comment: Sonic cracks a'la the tail end of a whip our a bullet crack.

Comment: The same way all the characters he moves doesn't die the moment he moves them. The sudden change in momentum would kill everyone of them in real life.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Marvel has not given a canon explanation why Quicksilver does not create sonic booms when he moves faster than sound.

> SPECULATION BASED ON OBSERVATIONS

#### Canon Continuity Earth-616

[Quicksilver, Pietro Maximoff](http://marvel.com/universe/Quicksilver) was a mutant and the son of the near-Omega class mutant, [Magneto](http://marvel.com/universe/Magneto_%28Magnus%29). He is also the brother of the mutant sorceress, [the Scarlet Witch](http://marvel.com/universe/Scarlet_Witch_%28Wanda_Maximoff%29). His x-gene adaptations gave him the ability to run at incredible rates of speed.

**They adaptations included:**

- A degree of superhuman strength (mostly in his lower body) and incredible stamina, a physiology capable of sustaining his hyper-fast movement due to nearly frictionless joints and a resilient skeletal structure. (In all the years, we have see Quicksilver fight, he rarely breaks a bone even when he is moving as super-speed.)
- He was also able to heal faster due to his accelerated metabolism.
- His brain was also accelerated, increasing his thinking processes and giving him the perceptual abilities to think in conjunction with using his power.

His power was written (as much as could be expected) to make sense as a adaptation or evolution with a plausibly-deniable sense of physics and science.

- This meant back in the day, his top speed was the speed of sound. He didn't make sonic booms because he needed quite a bit of room to run and he could barely sustain that speed for long.
- And yes, he would make a sonic event, but it wouldn't be called a boom, because he was not generating very much sound. Part of the [sound of sonic booms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom) comes from the engine sounds being compressed along the wing and nose of an aircraft.
- He was also quite material when he ran, he didn't have the power to phase through objects back then. Note his fight with Spider-Man and how Spidey ends the fight.

[image]

**Pietro has experienced significant power increases in recent years, with a corresponding lack of physics integrity.**

- These days, Quicksilver's power has graduated quite a bit. He is taking pages from DC's Flash, including running much faster than before (his top speed is now Mach 5).
- He is immune to the friction and any impacts taken while he utilizes his speed. He is able to run across the surface of the ocean or up the sides of buildings with ease.
- He is capable of molecular phasing: The power to control his molecular movement and pass through solid objects is the same power that makes him immune to friction and impact while running up to speeds of Mach 5.
- Molecular phasing would also be responsible for reducing his creation of sonic boom when moving faster than sound and avoiding damage, since he can be at least a bit out-of-phase while running, there is no pressure wave building up in front of him, compressing until he passes the speed of sound.

Thus, no sonic boom.

[image]

*Here is another canon appearance where he is moving at speeds far beyond the speed of sound without a corresponding boom.*